# OAuth and the YouTube API

Tags: python, oauth, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use the YouTube services with OAuth. I have been able to obtain request tokens, authorize them and transform them into access tokens.

Now I am trying to use those tokens to actually do requests to the YouTube services. For instance I am trying to add a video to a playlist. Hence I am making a POST request to

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/XXXXXXXXXXXX

sending a body of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <id>XXXXXXXXX</id>
</entry>
```

and with the headers

```
Gdata-version: 2
Content-type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="www.xxxxx.xx",
                                oauth_nonce="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                                oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
                                oauth_timestamp="1310985770",
                                oauth_token="1%2FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                                oauth_version="1.0"
X-gdata-key: key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

plus some standard headers (Host and Content-Length) which are added by urllib2 (I am using Python) at the moment of the request.

Unfortunately, I get an `Error 401: Unknown authorization header`, and the headers of the response are

```
X-GData-User-Country: IT
WWW-Authenticate: GoogleLogin service="youtube",realm="https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 179
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2011 10:42:50 GMT
Expires: Mon, 18 Jul 2011 10:42:50 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Connection: close
```

In particular I do not know how to interpret the WWW-Authenticate header, whose realm hints to ClientLogin.

I have also tried to play with the [OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) and the Authorization header sent by that site looks exactly like mine, except for the order of the fields. Still, on the plyaground everything works. Well, almost: I get an error telling that a Developer key is missing, but that is reasonable since there is no way to add one on the playground. Still, I go past the Error 401.

I have also tried to manually copy the Authorization header from there, and I got an `Error 400: Bad request`.

> What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the newline before `xmlns:yt`. I was able to debug this using ncat, as suggeested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/312094/manual-https-request/312102#312102), and inspecting the full response.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using the oauth python module, because it much more simple and takes care of the auth headers :) https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2, as a solution i suggest you encode your parameters with 'utf-8' , i had a similar problem, and the solution was that google was expecting utf-8 encoded strings

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. The headers only contain ASCII characters, and are URL-encoded, so there is no way I can tell urllib2 to use UTF-8