# Python oauth for youtube

Tags: python, django, oauth, youtube

I'm trying to implement youtube authenticated user's videos in my web application. Using oauth I want to connect to youtube apis. Here is the code I took it from github which I'm using now https://gist.github.com/2970845

I already implemented **vimeo api** with that code. But I don't know for Youtube api. It is showing this error when I'm requesting the `request_token`

```
<Response [400]>    
>>>r.text
u'parameter_absent\noauth_parameters_absent:oauth_consumer_key&oauth_signature_method&oauth_signature&oauth_timestamp&oauth_nonce&scope\n\n'
```

This is the sample request from Youtube reference page https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.

```
POST /accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth
oauth_consumer_key="example.com",
oauth_signature_method="RSA-SHA1",
oauth_signature="wOJIO9A2W5mFwDgiDvZbTSMK%2FPY%3D",
oauth_timestamp="137131200",
oauth_nonce="4572616e48616d6d65724c61686176",
oauth_version="1.0"
oauth_callback="http://www.example.com/showcalendar.html"

scope="http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds http://picasaweb.google.com/data"
```

What I'm not sure about is the headers I've shown in the gist page. I'm having like this

```
>>> headers
{'Authorization': u'oauth_body_hash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,oauth_nonce=62215234,oauth_timestamp=1340347725,oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,scope=https://gdata.youtube.com,oauth_callback=http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/youtube/'}
```

But the youtube reference page shows that we have to **use "Authorization: OAuth"**. How can I give that in the headers?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731966/oauth-and-the-youtube-api ??

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala I can't find my solution there. Could you give me the correct code?

Comment: i guess giving 2 urls in ur scope is messing things up

scope="http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds http://picasaweb.google.com/data" can you try giving just the calendars scope?

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala That is not my code actually. I'm using the code I've shown in the gist page.

Comment: ok, try using scope="http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds"

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to give another client library a shot (which incidentally wraps Requests), there's [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth). I don't have a YouTube example for you, but if you checkout the [existing examples](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples) on GitHub you can probably follow their format to get authenticated and make requests against YouTube's endpoints.

Now I realize there's all sorts of reasons why you may not be able to use another library, so no hard feelings if you can't. But I wanted to mention it as an option.

Comment: hi @maxcountryman, I checked the library few days before. It's cool..kudos for making it. Btw I solved the problem, but I forgot to post the answer. I'll do it soon.

Comment: @rnk can you please post the answer?